# WebApi and Ninject singleton scope

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject

Im using this article to get ninject to work with Asp.Net WebApi

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/using-ninject-with-the-latest-asp-net-web-api-source/

This breaks all scopes, like InSingletonScope

edit: Answer was in the comments

> Ok, I mostly figured it out. The problem is that the NinjectResolver's
>   BeginScope method returns a new NinjectScope passing in
>   _kernel.BeginBlock() to the constructor. This re-associates the instances from the scope that was declared in their bindings to the
>   new activation block.
>
> So, what was once scoped to the request is now scoped to the
>   activation block.
>
> To work around this I changed NinjectResolver like this:
>
> public IDependencyScope BeginScope() { return new
>   NinjectScope(_kernel); }
>
> Then, to keep the NinjectScope from disposing of the kernel itself, I
>   commented out everything in the NinjectScope's Dispose block.
>
> As far as I can tell, this should not have much impact. The built-in
>   cache-and-collect mechanism will work as it typically does, polling
>   the GC and disposing instances in the cache automatically.
>
> I think the core of the problem here is that WebApi itself is trying
>   to do the job of per-request scope management, but Ninject already has
>   a way of doing that job. The two different scoping mechanisms don't
>   seem to live in harmony.